# how to check previous scene in scene manager in unity 3d

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make my first game using unity 3d and I'm trying to make a game over the scene that when you press the `try again?` button it should take you back to the previous scene, I was thinking of just making it with the code `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1));` then just place one after every level on the build index so that it takes to the previous level that the player was in, but I think this would just increase the file size (Idk if it actually does), so I was wondering if there is a more efficient manner on how to do this so that I could only have one Game Over Scene in the Build Index?

Comment: If you want to add "how you fixed your issue", please create an answer with code and an actual explanation. Just posting an image is not considered as a valid answer, and answering in others posts is not really the way to go either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you considered storing your scene index just before loading the game over scene, and then returning to the stored index? Something like...

```
public class GameOver : MonoBehaviour {
    static int _lastSceneIndex;

    public static void GoToGameOverScene() {
        _lastSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
    }

    public void ReturnToLastScene() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(_lastSceneIndex);
    }
}
```

Now code in any other scene can call `GameOver.GoToGameOverScene()` to transition to the game over scene while remembering the scene it came from. Your try again button can call `ReturnToLastScene()` to go back.